# What is proper way to upload a image to a MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

What is the proper way to upload images into a MySQL database?

Generally, I declare the 'image' field as text and I use move_uploaded_file() function in order to save images on my server.

Is this the correct way to upload images into a database? I will have to upload lot of images, as social networking website might have to, for instance.

Comment: Yes it is a good way. Store images on file system and store their names in database

Comment: Controversial solution -- conventional wisdom might say to use db for pathnames and store actual images on file server.  All comes down to performance and needs though.  but take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: R u sure you have such a big database?  Its definitely not a correct idea to save images imto database..

Comment: I can't think of a reason you'd want to save images to the database rather than the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferably upload the image to server using File handling and PHP image libraries like GD and then store path as string in database. I think that should work.

Comment: I do the same thing. I wanted to know is it possible to save images into mysql database instead of saving path of the image.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two reliable ways to work with images into your database:

1 - Store the file in some folder at your server, then write the filepath in some field in your image table.

2 - Encode your image as base64 with the base64_encode($yourImageData) method. This method will return a string that can be inserted into your table.

Comment: The second one in my opinion is better than using BLOB field.
And worster than the first one.

Comment: Why is it better then using `BLOB` field?

Comment: I've got some problems with images within blob fields when :

1- Database grows and then i needed to restore backups with 10+ GB of data.

2 - Depending on your database structure, retrieving a dataset with images can slow significantly your queries. (This one i managed with a table only for blob files).

If you're sure that your database will not grow so much, blob fields can be a fast solution. Otherwise, having a nice abstraction for file handling solved nicely my problems.

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, it is not a good idea to save the image directly into database compared to save image on filesystem then save path/link to table fields.

but since the question is "upload images into mysql database"

I think you can check http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/